# angular/ui-mask country code from a phone number

Tags: angularjs, regex, angular-ui

I get the country code for the phone number from the database. And displayed using angular/ui-mask:

```
<input type="text" id="phone"  ui-mask="{{model.countryCode}} (XXX) XXX-XXXX"
    ui-mask-placeholder-char="X" required="" ng-model="employee.phone">
```

Everything works perfect if for example the country code is "375". But when the country code is "945" I get in my placeholder this: "X45 (XXX) XXX-XXXX".

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sheinar/Lvc0u55v/4427/

Comment: Can u provide more information about number from the database? Or a snippet.... cause I tested here and works fine

Comment: a working fiddle..

Comment: It is simply the json result {countryName: 945}. I think the problem is that the country meets the code number "9" and ui-mask replaces it as any numeric character

Comment: @АленаШлыкова Can you provide a link to the fiddle? Or add all the code right into your question?

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sheinar/Lvc0u55v/4427/